# Calling arbitrary number of object instances

Tags: java, object

```
import java.util.*;
public class UserInput {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many students are in your class?");
        Student.n= input.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<Student.n; i++){
            Student i = new Student(null, null, null, null, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

I am new to java and was just wondering if it's possible to call a number of object instances from a value inputted by the user during run time. Here "n" is the number of instances I want to make and I thought I could use the for method to refer to a variable "i" where it would create a new object instance for every "i" until it reached the inputted value of "n". However, I get a duplicate local variable error. So just wondering if there is any way around this????

Comment: declare `n` as a static data member.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is this:

```
ArrayList<Student> manyStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
for(int i=0; i<Student.n; i++){
    manyStudents.add(new Student(null, null, null, null, 0));
}
```

Comment: this is the correct way. but if you are a beginner, i would suggest to use a `Student` array instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @maxx777> This is not so advanced though.

Comment: Well in this case it can be an array too because he already knows ahead of time how many students he will have. But if he wants to dynamically add more students then he should definitely use an ArrayList.

Comment: @mok you are right but he is a beginner. You can see he even don't know about arrays (otherwise he won't have asked such question). There is no point in moving to collections before knowing the basics.

Comment: I like this idea of ArrayList, but is this still limited by the for loop?? So that it will create a new student instance and be stored in the ArrayList until i=Student.n?? Just making sure I am interpreting the code correctly

Comment: @user3545476> Yes, you create a new `Student` object on each iteration, and the total number of iterations is `Student.n`.